# Use lambda in the boost::geometry::for_each_point

Tags: c++, lambda, boost-geometry

I want to convert a `boost::model::polygon` to a `boost::model::multi_point`, and here is my implementation:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
typedef bg::model::point<double, 3, bg::cs::cartesian> point3d;

bg::model::multi_point<point3d> result;
std::function<void(point3d)> appendPoint = [result](point3d point){
    bg::append(result, point);
};

bg::for_each_point(polygon, appendPoint);
```

But this code give me an error:

```
error: passing ‘boost::remove_reference<const boost::geometry::model::multi_point<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> > >::type {aka const boost::geometry::model::multi_point<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>; _Alloc = std::allocator<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3ul, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

If I understand correctly, this kind of errors indicates about a problems with the const-correctness. But I really don't know, what is wrong in this code about `const`. Can anybody explaint me, where is my mistake, and hot to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument of `bg::append` should be reference to `result`, and `result` is captured by value in your lambda. Change the capture to

```
[&result](point3d point)
```

For capturing by value it reports errors about const correctness because you pass the temporary object as the argument expecting non-const reference. Were it const the error would not be reported.